# Issues with tkinter layout and ttk.Notebook

Tags: python, tkinter

I am attempting to create a Tkinter layout with 3 tabs using the ttk.Notebook class. Previously this was just done by

```py
tabControl = ttk.Notebook(root) #tabbed layout for multiple tasks
designTab = ttk.Frame(tabControl) #the rocket design tab
motorTab = ttk.Frame(tabControl) #the motor selection and data entry tab
calcTab = ttk.Frame(tabControl) #simulation / calculation tab
#pushing tabs to container
tabControl.add(designTab, text = "Design")
tabControl.add(motorTab, text = "Motor Configuration")
tabControl.add(calcTab, text = "Calculations")
```

however, the project is growing and the main file which renders the application needed to be moved to an object oriented system rather than the unstructured mess which it currently is. This involved moving each major part of the GUI to its own class, resulting in a class for each tab, i.e. there is a class for `designTab`,`motorTab`,`calcTab`. However, after copying the [existing](https://github.com/tpowell11/librerocket/blob/main/src/main.py) code over into the [new](https://github.com/tpowell11/librerocket/blob/main/src/new.py) file, the interface went from
[working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i8OZP.png)
to
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0VuZa.png).
as far as I can tell, all of the elements are generating on top of each other or not at all. I have been trying to get this to work for hours, any insight would be greatly appreciated. All code mentioned is [here](https://github.com/tpowell11/librerocket/tree/main/src) in the files main.py (the old, sloppy approach) and new.py (the OOP approach).
Thanks!

Comment: Please [edit]  your question to include a [mcve]. Links to offsite code are discouraged on this site.

Comment: After having a quick look it seems that there are widgets that have main as the parent when I think they're supposed to have self as the parent

Comment: I tired this and it didn't end up working, but I found that I could just import the file with the classes to have the same code-cleaning effect. Your change ended up making that process easier, so thanks.